# Access Facebook friend list who have logged in into an app angular-meteor app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am working on accessing user's friend list, who have logged in into app using Facebook in my angular-meteor app. I tried to use [Meteor facebook collection](https://github.com/maxkferg/meteor-facebook-collections), but I was not able to use it. So I tried to use Facebook graph API directly. My controller side code is:

```
 $meteor["loginWithFacebook"].call ({requestPermissions: ['user_friends']}).then (
    function (response) {
        //to get access token  
        Meteor.call("getAccessToken", function(error, fbAces){
           if (error) 
           {
              alert('error occured...');
            } 
            else
            {
                //to get user's facebook id
                Meteor.call("getFbId", function(error, fbId){
                    if (error) 
                    {
                      alert('error occured...');
                    } 
                    else
                    {

                       //to access user's friend list
                        Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+fbId+'/friends?access_token=' + fbAces ,function(error, result) {
                            if(error)
                            {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log(result);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }       
        });

    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Model side code is:

```
  getAccessToken : function() {
        try {
          return Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken;
        } catch(e) {
          return null;
        }
    },
    getFbId : function() {
        try {
          return Meteor.user().services.facebook.id;
        } catch(e) {
          return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried to use other graph api, it is returning correct data. But friends api is always returning blank data, but status code is 200. Please tell me how to access user's friend list. I am trying to solve this from last 2 days. Any help will be deeply appreciated.